# d3.js set attributes in v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following code works in D3 **v3**, but does not work in **v4**:

```
function render(data) {
  //bind
  var cirs = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);

  //enter
  cirs.enter().append('circle').attr('r', 2);

  //update
  cirs.attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y
  });

  //exit
  cirs.exit().remove();
}
```

My data:

```
var objects = [
  {x: 100, y:100},
  {x: 70, y: 90},
  {x: 181, y: 105},
  {x: 80, y: 60},
  {x: 160, y: 120},
  {x: 168, y: 182},
  {x: 95, y: 110}
]
render(objects);
```

I found that `cx` and `cy` are not set.

Is there a new way to set attributes in version 4?

Comment: Your question is missing some vital parts of your code. My first guess would be that you did not [`merge`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) your enter selection into the update selection whereby the calls to `attr()` will not be executed because the update selection is empty. Like I said, this is a rough guess. For more in-depth help please provide more of your `render()` function.

Comment: @altocumulus https://jsfiddle.net/dawit_jung/Lx20yvy3/ this is full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection) for v4 has the answer:

> In addition, [*selection*.append](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_append) no longer merges entering nodes into the update selection; use [*selection*.merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) to combine enter and update after a data join.

Therefore, your update selection will be empty and the calls to `.attr()` will never be executed resulting in the missing attribute values.

For your code to work, you just need to merge the previously entered circles into the update selection:

```
function render(data) {
  //bind
  var cirs = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);

  //enter
  var enter = cirs.enter().append('circle').attr('r', 2);

  //update (including merged enter selection)
  var update = cirs.merge(enter); // Merge the enter selection into the update selection
  update.attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y
    });

  //exit
  cirs.exit().remove();
}
```

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 250)
  .attr('height', 250);

function render(data) {
  //bind
  var cirs = svg.selectAll('circle').data(data);

  //enter
  var enter = cirs.enter().append('circle').attr('r', 2);

  //update (including merged enter selection)
  var update = cirs.merge(enter); // Merge the enter selection into the update selection
  update.attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y
    });

  //exit
  cirs.exit().remove();
}

var objects = [{
  x: 100,
  y: 100
}, {
  x: 70,
  y: 90
}, {
  x: 181,
  y: 105
}, {
  x: 80,
  y: 60
}, {
  x: 160,
  y: 120
}, {
  x: 168,
  y: 182
}, {
  x: 95,
  y: 110
}];

render(objects);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```